# How to custom order/sort json objects using java comparator?

Tags: java, json

I have json array of objects which will have "offer_name" field in every object. I would like to order/sort my json objects by custom defined "offer_name" order. Please let me know how can I achieve this?

I need to order offers in below order

```
enum OffersOrder { BEST("BEST"),GOLD("GOLD"),RISK("RISK"),STANDARD("STANDARD"),PUBLIC("PUBLIC");
String sound;    
OffersOrder(String s) { sound = s; }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? we will not write your code for you. show us what you have tried and we will try to help

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do that:

```
List<OffersOrder> l = new ArrayList<>();

// code to populate your list
...

// sorting
java.util.Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<OffersOrder>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(OffersOrder o1, OffersOrder o2) {
        // this method should return a negative value if o1 < o2
        // this method should return 0 if o1 == o2
        // this method should return a positive value if o1 > o2
        return 0;
    }
});
```